# How do I move the "Migrations" folder for EF Core 3 code first under a sub-folder in the same assembly that my DbContext is in?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0

When I perform an Add-Migration in EF Core 3.0 it by default wants to put the migration files under a folder called "Migrations" at the root of my DbContext project. How can I instead get it to create them in a "Migrations" folder that is under a folder called "Data" where "Data" is at the root of my DbContext project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think nothing changed so the command to put the migration in folder is `-o firstFolder/secondFolder`

```
Add-Migration MigrationName -o yourFolderPath
```